# HEX to BIN convert

Tags: c++

I wrote 2 programs that converts HEX to DEC and DEC to BIN.
When i test them seperatly they work.
When i place them together it outputs the right DEC code but the wrong BIN code.
How can i fix this?

## HEX to DEC

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
int hex;
std::cin >> std::hex >> hex;
std::cout << hex << std::endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

## DEC to BIN

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{   

int Number;
cin >> Number;
bool Binary[sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT];
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT; i++)
Binary[(sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1) - i] = Number & (1 << i);
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT; i++)
  std::cout << Binary[i];
std::cout << endl;

system ("pause");

return 0;

}
```

## HEX to BIN

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
int hex = 0;
int Number = 0;

std::cin >> std::hex >> hex;
std::cout << hex << std::endl;

hex = Number;

bool Binary[sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT];
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT; i++)
Binary[(sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1) - i] = Number & (1 << i);
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT; i++)
  std::cout << Binary[i];
std::cout << std::endl; 
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "the wrong BIN code"? Can you show examples of input and output? Also, what do you mean by "putting together"?

Comment: input: F (hex)
output: 15 (dec) and 0 (bin)

"putting together" so the program outputs the decimal value and the binary value from the inputted hex value

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want

```
Number = hex;
```

instead of

```
hex = Number;
```

Remember, assignment goes from *right* to *left*.

Answer (score 0):

```
hex = Number;
```

Your "HEX to BIN" part always operates on `0`. Always. Perhaps you meant `Number = hex;`.